# Dataself Dashboard filter not working

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, filters, tableau, visualforce-tab

I'm using DataselfBi, which is a Tableau subsidiary service. I'm trying to add a dashboard as a tab in Salesforce and when I try to filter it using the {!Account.OwnerId} as a filter parameter, and more. Nothing seems to work. Below is the code for the Visualforce tab.

```html
<apex:page standardController="account" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
 
  <apex:iframe src="https://dataselfbi.com/t/npcglobal/views/Dashboard1-2/Dashboard1?:embed=y&:showShareOptions=false&:toolbar=false&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no&(account)={ !Account.OwnerId}" height="800x" width="100%" scrolling="false">
 
  </apex:iframe>
 
 <apex:iframe src="https://www.dataselfbi.com/t/npcglobal/views/Dashboard1-2/Dashboard2?:embed=y&:showShareOptions=false&:toolbar=false&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no&(account)={ !Account.OwnerId}" height="800px" width="100%" scrolling="false">
 
  </apex:iframe>
 
 
</apex:page>
```